# Qt deploy not working on windows normally

Tags: windows, qt

I am using Visual Studio + Qt addon with Qt 5.15.2 x64 and set **Run deployment tool** to **Yes**. It seems like this deployment tool is poorly designed and broken. Never understand why Qt cannot make own runtime distibution for Windows like Microsoft did. After deployment when I am trying to open my release exe it just not open. Nothing happens. Yes, I can put it into qt bin folder that weights few gigabytes and it works, but it looks like deploy tool missed some libraries. How to deploy on windows without problems?

(Do not advice me to copy entire Qt bin and remove files one by one and find minimal combination of libraries, I want to make qt deploy automatically)

My errors on app launch:

```
qrc:/qml/main.qml:3:1: module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:3:1: module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:3:1: module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/qml/main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

Answer (score 1):

I found 3rd party Qt deploy toolkit for Windows. It just works fine out of box. I think the only way to solve problems with windeployqt is do not use it and switch to something else.

https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer

Answer (score 0):

I usually run `windeployqt` manually, if it help you:

```
path\to\windeployqt.exe --release --compiler-runtime path\to\release\build
```

for example

```
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\windeployqt.exe --release --compiler-runtime .\release
```

**Update:** if you use QML frontend in your app, as you described in question update, then also specify `--qmldir` argiment, so that `windeployqt` could find dependencies not only in compiled `.exe` import table, but also in non-compiled QML text files. See approved solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39717117/12691808.

Comment: I tried like this, still no success. Added errors to OP post.

Comment: @test123 did you try to specify `--qmldir` argument? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39717117/12691808

Comment: Yes, my app is QML based. Unfortunately no, this didn't help. But I found another working solution. This is 3rd party  qt deploying kit for windows. After it's deploy my app just works fine. https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer